# Trying to get camera in unity 2D to automatically scroll (not follow the player)

Tags: c#, camera, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a 2D platformer and want the camera to automatically start scrolling as the level starts and not follow the player. If the player leaves the camera zone they will die (already have this sorted). Just not that use to scritping cameras so any help would be much appreciated :)
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the update function to change the position of the camera gradually:

```
private void Update()
{
    float step = 5;

    var cameraPosition = Camera.main.gameObject.transform.position;
    cameraPosition.x += step;
    Camera.main.gameObject.transform.position = cameraPosition;
}
```

You will want to change `step` to be something relevant to your game, taking into account the width of the scene and the time you want the movement to take.